# onchange event repeats calculation after editing the same field

Tags: javascript, loops, concatenation, onchange

I have a javascript as below:

```
function calculateBill(id,price)
 {

var t = document.getElementById('total').value;


var qty = document.getElementById('qty_'+id).value;

var total = qty * price;


var tcost = Number(t) + Number(total);

document.getElementById('total').value = '';

//tcost = parseFloat(tcost);

document.getElementById('total').value = tcost.toFixed( 0 ) ;   
}
```

This function is called in a onchange event 
`<input type="text" id = "qty_<?php echo $i2; ?>" name="qty_<?php echo $i2; ?>" onchange="calculateBill('<?php echo $i2; ?>','<?php echo round($r2[$i2]['ret_price'],2); ?>')"  />`
Since its an onchange event, it calculates the total cost whenever I change the value. 
Now my problem is when I want to update the previously entered value, it calculates the new amount to old total.

( Suppose previous value for quantity is 2 , rate is 5 so total

5 * 2 = 10

Hence total is 10 from javascript function

Now if I edit the quanity to 1, insted of 5*1 = 5, I will get 10 + ( 5 * 1) = 15 ! 
)
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_total"/>
```

Make Hidden field value to have the initial total value when the form loaded.

now, inside the function, use the hidden_total value to add and set it to 0 once you are done with computing.

```
function calculateBill(id,price)
{
 var t = document.getElementById('hidden_total').value;
 var qty = document.getElementById('qty_'+id).value;
 var total = qty * price;
 var tcost = Number(t) + Number(total);
 document.getElementById('total').value = tcost.toFixed( 0 ) ;   
}
```

You might need to update the reset the value of hidden field once you have computed, depending on your need. In that case, add the following in the last line;

```
 document.getElementById('hidden_total').value = '';
```

Comment: Well it outputs only the individual totals,wherein I need to calculate current total amount !

Comment: what is current_total_amount? It is (price*quantity) or oldTotal+(price*quantity) ?

Comment: In my function `t = previous total cost`, `total = price for the current row`, `tcost = previous price + current row price`

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden value for old total like

```
<input type="hidden" id="old_total" value="<?=$total?>">
```

Just for the calculation use id `old_total`

```
var t = document.getElementById('old_total').value;
```

And to display output use id `total`

```
document.getElementById('total').value = tcost.toFixed( 0 ) ;
```